# Как корректно переписать код условия на Javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть условия выигрышных комбинаций игры, но видимо начал неправильно и получилось много кода. Получится так, если я еще буду делать условия для оппонента, кода станет в два раза больше.
Подскажите как это правильно и профессионально делается на Javascript?

[Вот ссылка на JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ufaj6kcm/13/)

Образец условий:

```
this.rezult = function(){
    this.arr2.forEach(function(arr, i, innerArr){
        arr.forEach(function(val, j){
            var wincomb = innerArr[i][j] === "X" && innerArr[i][j+1] === "X" && innerArr[i][j+2] === "X";
            var wincomb2 = innerArr[i][j] === "X" && innerArr[i+1][j] === "X" && innerArr[i+2][j] === "X";
            var wincomb3 = innerArr[i][j] === "X" && innerArr[i+1][j+1] === "X"&& innerArr[i+2][j+2] === "X";
            var wincomb4 = innerArr[i][j] === "X" && innerArr[i-1][j+1] === "X"&& innerArr[i-2][j+2] === "X";

            // console.log(wincomb == "X");
            // console.log(innerArr);

            if(wincomb || wincomb2){
                alert(' X wins!');
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По сути, твой вопрос - это "перепишите за меня программу", и, кроме того, проблемы твоего примера не в том "как это правильно и профессионально делается на Javascript", а в логическом подходе к самой структуре програмы (конкретный язык здесь уже вторичен). Кроме того, ты не удосужился ни описать достаточно подробно, что делает твоя программа, ни задокументировать код (мол, разбирайтесь как хотите, что это, как работает и что делает) - не надо так делать

По этому, полностью готовый и исправленный вариант я расписывать не стану, а ограничусь несколькими советами, из которых ты сам сможешь разобраться и создать то, что тебе конкретно нужно

Перепиши функцию `this.rezult`

а) Добавь возможность передавать в нее параметр, либо вынеси проверку в отдельную функцию, если хочешь использовать один фрагмент кода для обоих оппонентов. Что-то вроде такого:

```
this.proverka = function(param){
    var resultat = false;//По умолчанию - не правильно
    /*Код проверки [...], если условия выполняюся resultat = true;*/
    return resultat;
}
this.rezult = function(){
   var resultat = {X: this.proverka("X"), O:  this.proverka("O")}
  /*Получится что-то вроде {X: true, O: false} ( когда победил X)*/
}
```

б)Функия проверки. 
Во-первых используй лучше не forEach, а for (или for in) и break/continue и проходи им сразу по основному массиву innerArr

если я правильно понял суть, у тебя возможно только 3 варианта:

по диагонали из угла в угол (считай, имея ширину(кол. ячеек) (i_max) и высоту (j_max) поля, из угда innerArr[0,0] по возрастающей до innerArr[(i_max-1),(j_max-1)] и из угла innerArr[(i_max-1),0] по убыванию i innerArr[0,(j_max-1)]) - проверяешь наличие param (твоего "Х" или "О") в этих углах, затем проходишь циклом по диагонале:

```
/*Пример цикла*/
resultat = true; for(var z=0; z<i_max; z++){if(innerArr[z,z]!=param){resultat = false; break;}}
```

либо (если по прежнему resultat == false) остается возможность: полное заполнение столбца по вертикали или строки по горизонтали: соответственно, проходишь сначала 1ю строку и ищешь в ней param, если находится, начинаешь проверять столбец. Если столбец полный - готово, если нет - продолжаешь, пока не дойдешь до конца строки. Если ничего в строке не нешлось - значит столбцов нет - переходишь к проверке строк: берешь таким же образом 1й столбец и проходишься по нему таким же образом. Если и тут ничего не нашлось - то значит пользователь продул
Для строк будет выглядить примерно так:

```
for(var i=0; i<i_max; i++){//Перебор 1й строки

   if(resultat == true){break;}//Если предыдущие манипуляции уже дали положительный результат, то перебор прекращается (стоит вначале, чтобы перехватить как результаты предыдущих проходов цикла, так и манипуляций до него - иначе бы всю конструкцию пришлось бы обернуть в if(resultat == false){ [...] }

   if(innerArr[i,0]==param){ resultat = true;//Если что-то нашлось, мен. значение по умолчанию на положительное и начинаем перебирать столбец
     for(var j=0; j<j_max; j++){//Перебор столбца
        if(innerArr[i,j]!=param){resultat = false; break;}//Если облом - то результат сбрасывается снова на отрицательный и переборка столбца прерывается
     }
   }
}
```

Для перебора строк код аналогичный

Comment: Не стоит так сразу, за меня писать не нужно, так как я учусь и хочу делать это самостоятельно. Собственно и хотел узнать именно логический подход для данного типа задачи. За отсутствие подробностей задачи прошу прощения, буду знать на будущее как оформлять вопросы. 
За ответ премного благодарен.

Comment: А можно еще вопрос? Почему ты советуешь использовать for вместо forEach? Я им как раз и пытался пользоваться, так как читал, что это более удобный быстрый и "элегантный" способ :)

Comment: forEach - это пользовательская функция, построенная на for in, (выглядит примерно так  `forEach = function(callback){ for(var i in this){callvack.call(this[i], i, this[i]);}} )` и сделанная для удобства - в твоем случае, это во-первых, что палить по воробьям из пушки, (ты, к примеру, не используешь в своем приере val, но у тебя, фактически, целое нагромождение операций (пусть ты их и не видишь) там, где можно обойтись просто 2мя вложенными циклами). Во вторых, подход с "чистым"  for, на мой взгляд, дает больше возможностей с различными манипуляциями при переборе, чем уже готовая ф-ция с ним же

Comment: понял. еще раз большое спасибо :)